# Show bigger version of actor while actor is tapped libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

Let's say I have an actor `foo` and an actor `bar` which is the bigger version of the `foo` actor. How can I show `bar` next to `foo` while `foo` is tapped and then have have it disappear when `foo` is no longer being tapped (kind of like a tooltip)? `Foo` is in a stage2d table.
How can I show a bigger, more complete version of the actor while it is tapped?

Rough idea of what I want:

```
    Actor foo = new Actor();
    foo.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {

        public void touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // show bar next to foo (like a tooltip)
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // make bar dissapear
        }
    });
```

Code that kind of does what I want:
In this case toolTipCard is the actor I want to display when I touch one of the Strings from `selectedDeck`.

```
Stage collectionStage;
List<String> selectedDeck;
TestCard tooltipCard;
Vector3 touch = new Vector3();

            selectedDeck.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {

                public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
                    if (selectedDeck.getItems().size > 0) {
                        tooltipCard = new TestCard(game.cardFont, cardNameToCard.get(selectedDeck.getSelected()));
                        tooltipCard.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (7 * scale));
                        tooltipCard.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (3.3f * scale));
                        touch = viewport.unproject(touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
                        tooltipCard.setPosition(touch.x - tooltipCard.getWidth(), touch.y - tooltipCard.getHeight());
                        collectionStage.addActor(tooltipCard);
                    }
                }

                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    tooltipCard.remove();
                }
            });
```

Comment: create your own Image(foo), override draw method of that Image and draw bar (texture or label) with use of flag. change flat value on touchDown method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to get the position of the tapped actor (`foo`) and then add the other actor (`bar`) to the stage to that position translated with the size of the tapped actor (`foo`)?

Comment: No need to create another actor, only one Actor foo, bar is only part of foo, like a data member of your Actor.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments there are 2 options:

1. edit the draw method of an actor (if you need to show a very simple tooltip use this).
2. If you want to show a more advanced actor which can have it's own actions. You can get the foo's global coordinates and add an actor directly to the stage which you set visible/invisible (or fade in/out for a nicer look/feel).

To get the coordinates you can use: [localToStageCoordinates](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#localToStageCoordinates-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-)

```
Vector2 v = foo.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2());
```

or relative to its center:

```
Vector2 v = foo.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(foo.getWidth()/2,foo.getHeight()/2));
```

then use for instance: `bar.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(0.5f));` and `bar.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(0.5f));` to show/hide the tooltip

For optimization purposes you can reuse the bar actor for all foo instances on the screen and just repurpose it on every click. It is probably cheaper than creating a full actor for every one of them. However, if you can probably even create and destroy it on touch down/up without any problems.

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented what I wanted by getting the getting the position of the touch, unprojecting it and adding `bar` to the stage to that position (on touchDown), and then removing the actor from the stage on touchUp. However `foo` is actually a `List` of `String` and I want `bar` to appear when I click the string, The problem is that when I click on the list where there is no string it will show `bar` for the selected `String`, so `bar` won't appear exactly where it should. How could I get the position of the String? (localToStageCoordinates is for actors only)

Comment: I don't see how the string is an actor. Do you mean label? Please add the actual code you use to give me a better idea what you mean. Adding a screenshot/drawing could help too.

Comment: Added the code that I use. I guess a solution would be to change from List<String> to List<Label> ?

Comment: Yes, because you need actors that are added to a stage to use the input listener for that stage. Not sure how you can addListener on a List of strings..

Comment: You can addListener to the `List<String>` because it is a widget (a list box), and it can detect events that happen on it.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I was thinking of the Collections list. I have never worked with that list yet though. I would suggest you try to use List<Actor> and add the listeners to the children not the parent. Then they should handle their own touch events (if list actually works similar to a table) and you can handle the touches seperately